# Playing with C++20 Concepts

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-concepts

Is there any option to start playing with C++20 concepts? I have read the story about them written by Bjarne Stroustrup [Concepts - The Future of Generic Programming](http://www.stroustrup.com/good_concepts.pdf) and I am eager to try it out. But in GCC which I am about to use the concepts implemented are going to be implemented in GCC-10 earliest which is not yet availabĺe...

So is there an option to try it out? I tried to build GCC-10 from sources but there is no GCC-10 branch yet, just the trunk which seems to be broken by now (build failes due to missing some source file somehow)

So is there any way to try it out? Many thanks in advance to anyone willing to help!

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CYeC6P